# QgsRasterCalculator fails in standalone Python application

Tags: pyqgis, standalone

I am trying to write a simple Python program which shall be a wrapper for `QgsRasterCalculator()` function, to use it in some batch processes. In both QGIS 2.14 (on Linux) and QGIS 3.10 (on Windows 10) I have problems to find an expression that works.

Copying a raster, when the expression holds just the band reference works. But including an operator or a second band will fail.

E.g.:

```py
layer = QgsRasterLayer(path_to_dted_tile, 'n45_dt1') 
entries = [] 
band = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry() 
band.ref = layer.name() + '@1' 
band.raster = layer 
band.bandNumber = 1 
entries.append(band)

expression = '"n45_dt1@1"'

context = QgsCoordinateTransformContext()  # QGIS 3.10 only 
calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression,
                           path_to_output_file,
                           'GTiff',
                           layer.extent(),
                           layer.width(),
                           layer.height(),
                           entries,
                           context)   # QGIS 3.10 only 
result = calc.processCalculation()
```

works as expected. When I use: `expression = '"n45_dt1@1" + 1.0'`

`QgsRasterCalculator` crashes with the following output on the console:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

If the expression is wrong, how should it look like and, if not, what may cause this failure?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is not your expression. I checked this out using the Raster calculator from the Processing Toolbox and observed the same issue in QGIS 3.10.0. The same thing works in QGIS 3.4.14 LTR as you can see in Screenshot:

[image]

I bet that your python code with the `'"raster@1" + 1.0'` expression will work in the current LTR too.

Just opened an issue for this: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32477

Comment: In deed pyqgis 3.4.14 LTR works for an expression with a single raster and an operator. A more complex expression with two rasters fails. But using the processing tool again works. I am out of ideas now.

Comment: Could you provide example?

Comment: Python script and batch file to start the script have been uploaded to GIST repo, along with 2 raster tiles to test against https://gist.github.com/detlevn/ae6b6d06e2547a5db52b5d8c991581e1 See comment on GIST on how to unpack the test files.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for Raster Calculator issue in Qgis 3.10 is:
1. Goto the Qgis 'Setting',
2. Option,
3. Acceleration,
4. Then, check the box 'Enable OpenCL acceleration’ 
This will work sure.